# Filter a dataframe based on today's date (On or before today) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Unit_ID    Added_Date                   Status         
105        2019-10-02 08:14:16          Rented
106        2020-10-21 07:19:13          Rented
109        2020-01-02 07:18:19          Rented
108        2020-06-01 04:15:28          Vacant
```

From the above data I would like to filter the data on or before today's date in the column 'Added_Date'.

Expected Output:

```
Unit_ID    Added_Date                   Status         
105        2019-10-02 08:14:16          Rented
109        2020-01-02 07:18:19          Rented
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Make sure your date column is a date an not a string
df['Added_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Added_Date'])
# Compare with today's date
df.loc[df['Added_Date'] > pd.Timestamp(datetime.now()), 'Added_Date']
```

which outputs:

```
1   2020-10-21 07:19:13
3   2020-06-01 04:15:28
Name: Added_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`pd.to_datetime()` and `pd.Timestamp()` ensures that the dates are in the same format and can be compared with the standard pandas operators.

Comment: I would like to have full data frame.
Can I do using this?
df[df['Added_Date'] > pd.Timestamp(datetime.now())]

Comment: Rather do: ```df.loc[df['Added_Date'] > pd.Timestamp(datetime.now()), 'Added_Date'].to_frame()```